# Why "c'est plus pareil" translates to "It's not the same" ?

Tags: expressions, négation

I was translating a song lyric and saw that the expression *"c'est plus pareil"* translates to *"it's not the same"*. This translation doesn't make sense to me, as there are no negation words like *"ne"* or *"pas"*. For me, the right expression should be *"ce n'est pas plus pareil"*. The expression  *"c'est plus"* indicates negation? I couldn't find that expression by searching in dictionaries.

Comment: « c'est pareil » = « cela est identique », est-ce qu’on peut être *plus* identique ? … alors cela est *moins* pareil, donc « ce ***n'*** [*ne plus* pour être correct, sinon langage familier)] est *plus* pareil » = « cela est *moins* identique ».

Comment: @PeterShor  … « moins pareil » [n'est pas usité, sauf par les très jeunes enfants] = « c'est devenu différent », il y a une comparaison avec une situation antérieure observée

Comment: "C'est plus pareil" translates more accurately to "it is no longer the same" or "we're not discussing the same thing anymore". The negation comes from "plus" which means "no longer". (Also yeah, missing the "ce n'est" part but that's just colloquial)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first part of split negatives (***ne***) tend to disappear in French, so ***c'est plus pareil*** is simply the spoken French version of ***ce n'est plus pareil*** ("**it's no longer the same**").

Here *plus* is enough to understand it is a negation, especially when hearing the sentence because its final ***S*** is not pronounced.

There is then another ***c'est plus pareil*** where the same ***S*** is heard (/plys/ vs /ply/). This form stays the same whatever the language register and means "**It's more the same**".

Note also that ***ce n'est pas plus pareil*** is unlikely to be heard but would be understood (with /ply/) as a double negative "**it's not no longer the same**".

Comment: Bien d'accord avec vous, sauf pour le **c'est plus pareil** dans le sens positif qui ne serait jamais utilisé par un natif, de mon point de vue. On utiliserait **ça ressemble plus** (avec S final prononcé) ou encore **c'est plus ressemblant** (en parlant d'un dessin, par exemple).

Comment: @XouDo Peu probable, certainement, mais jamais, non. Impossible de distinguer les ***pluss** pareil* des ***plu** pareil* mais on rencontre quelques *c'est **moins** pareil* dans des forums, donc à l'oral, nul doute que *c'est **pluss** pareil* doit pouvoir s'entendre. Je conviens que ça a peu de chance de se dire ou lire dans un registre soutenu vu la liberté que l'expression prend avec la logique...